# How I can use the value of a textbox which is in a gridView in the code behind without using the FindControl() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can do I that? Does anyone have a solution. It is also looking tricky but I don't have an answer.

Comment: This depends on what you want to do with the textvalue and how you want to access it(e.g. javascript, or on postback). Please provide more details

Comment: Definately need more details. What's the reason for not using FindControl()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0])

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function SelectAll(id)
  {
    //get reference of GridView control
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");
    //variable to contain the cell of the grid
    var cell;

    if (grid.rows.length > 0)
    {
      //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
      for (i=1; i<grid.rows.length; i++)
      {
        //get the reference of first column
        cell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];

        //loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
        for (j=0; j<cell.childNodes.length; j++)
        {       
          //if childNode type is textbox or label or...         
          if (cell.childNodes[j].type =="TextBox")
          {
          //perform ur task here
        }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I want to use in code behind not by javascript. thanks for providing this superb code